# How can I draw a route on the Map control?

Tags: user-interface, routes

I have included a map in my UI and want to show the route from the current position of the device to a location (e.g. restaurant). How can I do that?

Comment: Please share what have you attempted

Comment: What map? What are you working on? iOS? Android? HTML web page? Apple Watch? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what technology you're looking at, but in case you want something like that on Windows - The UWP platform provides methods to calculate a route and then plot that on the map.

What you need is the `MapControl` and the `MapRouteFinder` to calculate the route from a start GPS position to an end GPS position. From the result you can create a `MapRouteView` that can be added to the `MapControl`. Remember to also check the `Location` capability in the `appmanifest`. You could do it like this:

```
// get the user's consent to determine the location
var status = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
if (status == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    // get the current position
    Geolocator locator = new Geolocator() { DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High };
    Geoposition pos = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    BasicGeoposition current = new BasicGeoposition()
            { Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Latitude,
                Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Longitude };

    // set the lat/long of the restaurant
    BasicGeoposition restaurant = new BasicGeoposition()
            { Latitude = 51.91997, Longitude = 4.486515 };

    // get the driving route
    MapRouteFinderResult route = 
            await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(new Geopoint(current), 
                                                        new Geopoint(restaurant), 
                                                        MapRouteOptimization.Time, 
                                                        MapRouteRestrictions.None);
    // get the view and add it to the map
    MapRouteView routeView = new MapRouteView(route.Route);
    routeView.RouteColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
    TheMap.Routes.Add(routeView);

    // change the view of the map to see the complete route
    await TheMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(route.Route.BoundingBox, 
                                        null, MapAnimationKind.Default);
}
```